# ag-grid react to display boolean value instead of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In AG-Grid-react, If API response has boolean value say true or false, then by default ag-grid-react shows checkbox. IS there a property in ag-grid-react to display value as true or false in column and not checkbox.

Can anyone help if there is any property to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the property [cellDataType](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-data-types/) and set it to string, so that you do not get the checkbox but the actual value!

```
import { ColDef } from "ag-grid-community";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

// Row Data Interface
interface IRow {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  price: number;
  electric: boolean;
}

// Create new GridExample component
const GridExample = () => {
  // Row Data: The data to be displayed.
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<IRow[]>([
    { make: "Tesla", model: "Model Y", price: 64950, electric: true },
    { make: "Ford", model: "F-Series", price: 33850, electric: false },
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", price: 29600, electric: false },
  ]);

  // Column Definitions: Defines & controls grid columns.
  const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState<ColDef<IRow>[]>([
    { field: "make" },
    { field: "model" },
    { field: "price" },
    { field: "electric", cellDataType: "string" },
  ]);

  // Container: Defines the grid's theme & dimensions.
  return (
    <div
      className={"ag-theme-quartz"}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    >
      <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={colDefs} />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render GridExample
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(<GridExample />);
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-packages-forked-mh3xr7?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A1%2C1-47%2C1)